# value of variable vanishes

Tags: php, var

I do not understand what is happening with my variables, the values all vanish / become empty within the function. I don't have anything within the function. I believe that I am doing the 'checks' correctly `'=='` and the assignments correctly `'='`. Regardless of what i try, i continue to get the 'file doesn't exist result'. and if i `var_dump` to see what the value of `$cID` or `$check`, they come back as empty ''.

```
function gt_masthead($cID='3', $check=false, $str=''){ //assign value to var

$check == file_exists('./' . $cID . 'bg-userProfile.jpg');  //file exists?

    //echo '<h1> / ' . $cID . ' / ' . $check . ' </h1>';

    dumpVar($cID);  //test

    if($check == 1){
        // file exists, show
        $str = '<img class=" img-fluid" style="width: 100%;" src="./3bg-userProfile.jpg" alt="Card image cap">';
    }else{
        // file does not exist, show default
        $str = '<img class=" img-fluid" style="width: 100%;" src="./img_logoMarvel.gif" alt="Card image cap">';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? your arguments are optional

Comment: If you're not passing parameters to you function, why are you adding them in the parenthesis instead of inside the function?

Comment: `$check == file_exists('./' . $cID . 'bg-userProfile.jpg');` why are you using `==` instead of `=`? You're doing a comparison, but not doing anything with the result of that comparison

Comment: Your assignments are correct (except for the `$check` variable, that should just be an `=`), but we need to see how you are calling the function

Comment: The dumpVar() function is not defined. Or is it supposed to be var_dump()?

Comment: When I change the dumpvar -> var_dump it seems to run as expected. https://3v4l.org/oV2ru

Comment: I revised the the function with with the double check, the same result persists. I am currently manually adding them to make sure they hold the values I expect for purposes of testing. The dumpVar function is defined in custom file - it just makes a pretty var_dump (it adds 'pre' tags.

Comment: We still need to see the way you are calling the function. And what is your expected result vs what you are actually getting?

Comment: I call the function like so '<? echo  gt_masthead($cID, $str=''); ?>'

Comment: That isn't how you call a function. You don't define a variable like that in a function

Comment: Ok.. But look at the link above, and this link here: https://3v4l.org/njblg  it works. In this link I added ! at file exist.

Comment: You should just be calling `gt_masthead()` since the parameters are set my default and you are setting the `$check` variable to `$str=''` instead of `true/false`

Comment: My expected result is that I will see the background image i want instead of the default background image. The default is only to show if the the requested image does not exist. Instead while the requested image exists, the default image shows instead.

Comment: This is how you use a function. You set the ID before you call the function and then you return the str. https://3v4l.org/PRpPB

Comment: I did do that (set them first) but they came in empty -- so i wanted to get the function work and then work my way out. but that wasn't working so i set them manually to make sure they were entering the function AS expected. At least that was what I thought i was doing anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
<?php
    function gt_masthead($cID, $image = "bg-userProfile.jpg", $default = "img_logoMarvel.gif") { //assign value to var
        //check if given image file exists
        if(file_exists("./{$cID}{$image}")) {
            //if it does exist, set the displayImage variable to the path of the image.
            $displayImage = "./{$cID}{$image}";
        } else {
            //if it does not exist, set the displayImage variable to the path of the default image
            $displayImage = "./{$default}";
        }
        //Add the displayImage path to an image element, and return that element.
        $str = "<img class='img-fluid' style='width:100%;' src='{$displayImage}' alt='Card image cap'>";
        return $str;
    }
?>
```

The usage of this code is pretty simple. You call it like this:

`gt_masthead("cID number", "image name");` - you can also use variables here, just drop the quotes.

Alternatively, you can also use a 3rd variable to dynamically set the default image if the searched one does not exist.

`gt_masthead("cID number", "image name", "default image name");`

I commented the code to try to explain what is going on. If you have any questions please ask

---

Here is a more *standard* way to write the function, I know the squiggly braces sometimes confused people, but the code is basically the same.

```
<?php
    function gt_masthead($cID, $image = "bg-userProfile.jpg", $default = "img_logoMarvel.gif") { //assign value to var
        //check if given image file exists
        if(file_exists("./".$cID.$image)) {
            //if it does exist, set the displayImage variable to the path of the image.
            $displayImage = "./".$cID.$image;
        } else {
            //if it does not exist, set the displayImage variable to the path of the default image
            $displayImage = "./".$default;
        }
        //Add the displayImage path to an image element, and return that element.
        $str = "<img class='img-fluid' style='width:100%;' src='".$displayImage."' alt='Card image cap'>";
        return $str;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I figured out the issue - i was testing against the virtual path instead of the physical path. Thank you for the notes  -  they are all appreciated.